# @HostBinding initial @Input value ignored

Tags: angular, angular2-hostbinding, angular2-inputs

I have a directive that helps with adding toggle effects to various elements.

```
export class AlloyToggleDirective {
    private toggled = false;

    @Input('alloyToggled')
    @HostBinding('class.alloy-toggled')
    get isToggled() { return this.toggled; }
    set isToggled(value: boolean) {
      this.toggled = value;
      this.alloyToggledChange.emit(this.toggled);
    }
    @Output() alloyToggledChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

    toggle() {
      this.toggled = !this.toggled;
    }

    @HostListener('click')
    onclick() {
        this.toggled = !this.toggled;
        this.alloyToggledChange.emit(this.toggled);
    }
}
```

It works fine when toggled, however the initial bound value is ignored:

```
<button [alloyToggled]="booleanValue">
```

The HTML will reflect that initial value, but the class is only applied after toggling programmatically or via mouse.  Is there a strange interaction when `@HostBinding` is on an `@Input`?

Comment: I'd guess that `alloyToggled` and `toggled` are fighting from the start. Since the **get** applies **false** from the start you will always receive **false**. Is there a reason you're not using `alloyToggled` throughout, and have the `private toggled`?

Comment: Check out this stackblitz, I think it'll help clear up Directives for you: https://stackblitz.com/angular/naavjopgege?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html (also, help with @Input syntax)

Comment: If that were true, the `onClick` and changes to `booleanValue` wouldn't work.  However, they do.  It's _only_ the initial value of `booleanValue` that is ignored.

Comment: Are you actually manually changing "booleanValue" within your component? At second glance it appears both "alloyToggled" and "booleanValue" are ignored and not even part of the equation here.

Comment: For testing I swap `booleanValue` programmatically.  It start `true`, but doesn't apply `alloy-toggled`.  Clicking once does nothing, it switches to `false` and hence should not have the class.  A second click applies the class, since the internal boolean is now true.  So the initial value _does_ get set in the directive, however, `HostBinding` simply ignores it.  However, it's content to listen to all following changes.

Same behavior from `host` metadata.

Comment: Hope that answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems:

- @Input definition
- Variable syntax mixups

**directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[alloyToggled]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    @Input('alloyToggled') alloyToggled: boolean;
    @HostBinding('class.alloy-toggled')
    get isToggled() { return this.alloyToggled; }
    set isToggled(value: boolean) {
      this.alloyToggled = value;
      this.alloyToggledChange.emit(this.alloyToggled);
    }
    @Output() alloyToggledChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

    toggle() {
      this.alloyToggled = !this.alloyToggled;
    }

    @HostListener('click')
    onclick() {
        this.alloyToggled = !this.alloyToggled;
        this.alloyToggledChange.emit(this.alloyToggled);
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<button [alloyToggled]="booleanValue">Toggle Alloy</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  booleanValue = true;
}
```

HighlightDirective edited to mirror you expected code behavior.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lrmveu

Created from the Angular Highlight Example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/naavjopgege?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Interestingly, plugging my code into your stackblitz also works.  It must involve the interaction with the host component then...

Comment: Turns out another dev had added some logic related to menus that sets `alloy-toggled` in the button.  Since I wrote most of the code in the library it didn't even occur to me to check internally to button..._sigh_

Thanks for the help, marking it as the answer since it ended up pointing me at the tertiary culprit.